# What amount of forrest-fire in square km or metric tons, would be necesary to bring oxygen levels below 19.5% that humans require to stay alive?

Tags: life, fire, oxygen, cataclysms

I read that oxygen makes up 21% of the Earth's atmosphere. I'm guessing it would take a lot of burning to decrease that level, but I am not sure how to calculate that.
The problem is: Roughly 400 hundred years in the future, humans are thinking they need to burn some forests made predominantly of a plant species that produces a gas toxic to humans and other life-forms, that spread on Earth and suffocated a lot of other useful (for us) plant species.  They were worried that the large-scale fires would lower the amount of oxygen in the atmosphere to a level that humans would suffocate, but I can tell from the existing answer, that’s not going to be a problem, so they can go ahead with the plan.
I got the 19.5% threshold from this article: https://sciencing.com/minimum-oxygen-concentration-human-breathing-15546.html 
But on a closer reading, I noticed it said the OPTIMAL range is between 19.5% and 23.5%, and the CRITICAL threshold for survival is 6%, so my mistake. Again, this makes the worries of the people in my story unfounded.
My question has been answered, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your question: Do you literally want to set the (fictional) world on fire to bind enough oxygen to: (A) lower the amount of oxygen in the atmosphere to a level that humans would suffocate or (B) Change the composition of the atmosphere so that oxygen makes up 19,5% of the volume? Please keep in mind that oxygen content depends on the altitude (people on Mt. Everest suffocate even in our current atmosphere).

Comment: Are you saying people would suffocate if oxygen drops below 19.5 volume percent? That sounds extremely strange. Do you have any source for it?

Comment: See also, here: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/percentage-of-oxgen-left-after-burning-all-the-available-biomass/8960#8960

Comment: I don't know where you got that 19.5% figure from but it's way off. I've done some pretty tough cycling at an [altitude equivalent to around 15% at sea level](https://www.higherpeak.com/altitudechart.html) -- it was certainly hard but people live higher than that. Here's a nice paper [Hypsographic demography: The distribution of human population by altitude,
Joel E. Cohen and Christopher Small,
PNAS November 24, 1998 95 (24) 14009-14014](http://www.pnas.org/content/95/24/14009) showing that around 20% of people have less than 19.5% O2 sea level equivalent due to altitude

Comment: ... effectively you're just lifting everyone by about 600m (the source @mathreadler asked for probably doesn't exist, in other words). Some people live above 4000m, which is equivalent to 12% O2 at sea level

Comment: Welcome to the site, to clarify some of the comments above:  Stack Exchange is a little different from your standard discussion forum.  The site is about specific questions with specific supported answers.  As it stands your question while potentially interesting is not fully developed.  Check out the  [tour] and [help] to get a better idea how the site functions.  [How to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) will give you guidance on writing questions.  Again welcome and happy world building.

Comment: Just so you're aware, while we encourage people to edit their questions to bring them on topic, we prefer if it's done in a way that doesn't invalidate the existing answers. Even if your original numbers were incorrect, L.Dutch's highly-rated and accepted answer relies on those numbers.

Comment: @F1Krazy Ok, thanks, I left it in the title and clarified in the details. Will this work?

Comment: @ChrisH Here is a link which references some official OHSA guide lines https://www.osha.gov/pls/oshaweb/owadisp.show_document?p_id=25743&p_table=INTERPRETATIONS . Please remember that if your fit and healthy your not going to be impacted the same way as your average person and that people who live higher altitudes have often adjusted to that altitude. 19.5% isn't exactly dangerous, but if your reach 19.5% from 21% its likely going to keep dropping which starts to make it risky for your average Joe.

Comment: @Shadowzee, that guidance is applicable up to 14000ft, so actually allows quite a low partial pressure while people are expected to work. It may be the source of the number but it doesn't support the aspect of killing most/all people as in the question (as written). Statistically it would lead to a rise in the death rate, of course, but you'd be talking small numbers mostly in remote areas. Maybe high altitude cities would be a bad idea for those with respiratory conditions but they'd have time to move - the drop wouldn't be instant. Moot now anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's start with considering the entire [mass of the atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Density_and_mass):

> The total mean mass of the atmosphere is $5.1480 \cdot 10^{18} kg$.

We know that Oxygen accounts for 21% in volume, and considering that

> The density of air at sea level is about $1.2 \ kg/m^3$

We get that the "sea level" volume of the entire atmosphere is

$V =$$ 5.1480 \cdot 10^{18} \over 1.2$$=4.29 \cdot 10^{18} m^3$.

You want to consume 1.5% of that volume (21 - 19.5), thus you want to consume

$M_{O_2}=4.29 \cdot10^{18} [m^3]\cdot 0.015 \cdot 1.429 $$ [{kg\over m^3}]$$= 9.19 \cdot 10^{16} kg$ of Oxygen, considering that Oxygen density is $1.429 $$ [{kg\over m^3}]$.

Assuming you want to burn Carbon to consume all that Oxygen, how much Carbon would you need?

The chemical reaction for Carbon oxidation is

$C + O_2 = CO_2 + heat$

therefore for each mole of Oxygen you need a mole of Carbon. Considering that Oxygen to Carbon atomic weight ratio is 32/12, you would need

$M_C = M_{O_2} \cdot $$12 \over 32$ $=9.19 \cdot 10^{16} \cdot $$12\over 32$$=3.5 \cdot 10^{16} kg$ of Carbon.

The [2011 estimated coal reserves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal#Market_trends) in the entire world amount to $891 \cdot 10^{12} \ kg$, just to give you a reference.

As additional note, burning that much carbon would release (taking the heat of combustion of anthracite)

$Heat = 32 [MJ/kg] \cdot 891 \cdot 10^{12} \ [kg] = 28.5 \cdot 10^{15} \ MJ$, corresponding to about $6.7 \cdot 10^6 MTon$, or about 1 million Tsar bombs...

Comment: Beat me to it. According to this website, the total mass of carbon based life is 5,5e14 kg. So.… pretty hard to do that.  https://www.vox.com/science-and-health/2018/5/29/17386112/all-life-on-earth-chart-weight-plants-animals-pnas

Comment: On top of that as atmospheric levels dropped the oceans would give up dissolved oxygen back to the atmosphere as well, there'a about 970 million cubic kilometers of O2 down there.

Comment: @Jens you got me wondering. Given that there was no oxygen in atmosphere until life freed it from co2, and some oxygen sank into iron oxide before atmosphere started to accumulate o2 — where did all that carbon go? We should have more than enough to bring atmospheric levels to 0, and it looks like we don't have enough to get it down by mere percents.

Comment: @Mołot there was no *free* oygen. But what about H2O? And probably some other nasty stuff full of oxygen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_elements_in_Earth%27s_crust

Comment: @DonQuiKong yes, but Oxygen Catastrophe theory assumes free one was created by photosynthesis - and photosynthesis basically splits CO2 to O2 and biological carbon compounds. Something doesn't add up for me. @ anyone - do you know which Stack site (if any) would accept such question?

Comment: @Mołot wild guess: Earth Science?

Comment: @Mołot: Answer: the Oxygen Catastrophe was followed by limestone precipitation which removed the excess carbon from the biosphere.

Comment: @L.Dutch I was torn between Earth Science, Biology, and What Do I Know ;) I'll think about it a bit more and maybe try to ask on Earth.

Comment: @Joshua, limestone is CaCO3...

Comment: @L.Dutch: Yeah, and the O3 came from water releasing H which is eventually lost to space.